# boost non-blocking read write routines for multithread program

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads, nonblocking

I am coding for data exchange between threads by boost C++.

Some threads need to read or write some data structure asynchronously.

For example,  we have thread 1 and thread 2.

When thread 1 needs to get some data from thread 2, if the data is still not available for thread 1, 
it should not be blocked and can do other things and then go back to check the data again later.

The same things are for thread 2.

What are the API routines of boost non-blocking read write , which can do that ?

I cannot find it in boost document.

I find something for solaris here:

http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWdev/MTP/p31.html

I need API routines that can support:

(1) post the read write routine at first 
(2) do other things
(3) then go back to check whether the data has been available or not

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the *structures* are standard containers, you can just keep track of the container size. If it's larger than previous check then there is new data.

If you read from file descriptors, make them non-blocking. Reading from them would then return an error of `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

**Edit** As another poster said, you can always use a [mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts). Try to lock the mutex, and if it fails continue to do other work.

**Edit 2** If the size of the container is static, then you need some other signaling or communication between the threads. Mutexes/condition variables comes to mind, or adding a flag to the container saying it has been modified. The flag in the container only works if there is one reader of the container, as the reader should clear the flag when done.

Comment: the data container size is the same but its contents are different at each iteration.

Comment: @user1002288 Can you modify the container to have a flag that tells is there is new content in it?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the API routines of boost non-blocking read write , which can do that ?

Who says that there are any? It's generally up to you to create higher-level functionality like that. Boost.Thread is for creation of threads and managing synchronous communication between them.

You can easily build this with a pair of mutexes. When the producer thread is done producing data, it releases its lock on a mutex, which allows the consumer thread to start consuming. You use the other mutex to prevent the producer from producing new data into the buffer until the consumer has finished consuming.

Comment: how to make data producer notify the consumer that the new data is available so that the consumer can be told as fast as possible ?

Comment: @user1002288: That's up to you. Your consumer thread cannot be made to start processing something else; it has to stop and check periodically if something is available. Are you sure you don't just want your consumer to block on the mutex instead, giving up its timeslice to some other thread which would do the "other work" you're talking about? That would probably a more efficient way to do it than to be constantly polling the mutex.

Comment: I need non-blocking read/write to an element of a large data structure, which is a stl::map<string, struct>. At one point of time, each thread needs to read/write one element of the map, e.g. map[i]. I need the mutex that only lock element map[i] not other elements, because other threads may need to read/write them at the same time.

Comment: The size of the map is constant but its elements' contents are always updated at each iteration.

Comment: @user1002288: Have you considered structuring your code in such a way that what you're trying to do is not needed? Or that you're able to do it in a different way? Because really, what you're trying to do is very special-case. There is almost certainly a more efficient way to get it done.

Comment: where is not efficient ?  the map or the mutex lock ? the threads need map to exchange data.